# Python - List of variables

Tags: python

I don't know if it is possible in Python but here is what I intend to do

```
var = 5
array=[]
array.append(var)
array[0] = 1
```

I want `var` and `array[0]` to be updated with 1 and print 1:

```
print(array[0])
print(var)
```

Is it possible in Python to send in a pointer and dereference the pointer value to change it?

Comment: No. What are you actually trying to do? This might be a variable variables question in disguise, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-do-variable-variables-in-python

Comment: @timgeb That will work. With a dictionary this will work, because I just wanted to give the value a name(meaning). Thanks

Comment: BTW, `array` is not a great name for a list because it's the name of the standard Python module that defines actual arrays.

Comment: I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python doesn't really have variables*, Python has names. See [Facts and myths about Python names and values](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html) by Ned Batchelder.

Therefore, C-like concepts of pointers don't translate well to Python. `var` is just a name that points to the integer object `5`; by appending `var` to `array`, you created another reference to that object, not a pointer to `var`.

Whatever you're trying to do might be better serviced by, for example, a dictionary:

```
vars = {"var": 5}
array = []
array.append("var")
vars[array[0]] = 1

print(vars[array[0]]) # prints "1"
print(vars["var"])    # ditto
```

---

<sup>*In the abovementioned article, Ned Batchelder writes that "names *are* Python's variables". In other words, Python does have variables, but they work in a different way than variables in, say, C or Java.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible in python. (`list` is mutable but `integer` is immutable) You can use aliasing of mutable objects to achieve a similar effect.

So you can do like this,

```
>>> var = [5]
>>> array = []
>>> array.append(var)
>>> var[0] = 3
>>> array
[[3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this could also work for you:

```
val=[]
array=val
array.append(5)

# it is all aliased so everything should be equal
print val[0], array[0], val == array
```